# Is there a "practical" Hilbert space of stochastic processes?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces

It is well-known that one can construct a Hilbert space of zero mean, finite variance random variables such that every random variable of this type $X$ can be represented as a linear combination of a sequence of random variables $F_i$ with respect to probability:

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\text{cov}(X,F_i)}{\text{var}(F_i)}F_i$$

**Is there any such meaningful Hilbert space construction for stochastic processes $X(t)$?**

Comment: Is this what you have in mind? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem

Comment: @MikeHawk That’s essentially it—although I expected deterministic coefficients on a sequence of stochastic processes instead of stochastic coefficients on a sequence of deterministic processes, I’ll take what I can get; feel free to put it down as an answer and I’ll give you the bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any square-integrable process on a finite interval $[a,b]$ can be written $X_t=\sum_i Z_i e_i(t)$ where $Z_i$ are uncorrelated, $e_i$ are an orthonormal basis of $L^2$, and the convergence is in $L^2$. This is called the Karhunen-Loeve decomposition, and much more information can be found on the Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem

Comment: Jumping on this to mention that the stochastic process $X_t$ can also be viewed as a linear operator between $L^2$ and the Hilbert space of mean-$0$ random variables mentioned in the OP. In this framework, the decomposition of $X_t$ into that sum can be thought of as the infinite-dimensional analogue of the singular-value decomposition of the operator